# why does Hibernate's EntityManager.find() impl throw EntityNotFoundException?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

JPA 2.0 [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29) (and probably the spec) say that EntityManager.find() returns null when entity isn't found:

> the found entity instance or null if the entity does not exist

Yet Hibernate's impl throws EntityNotFoundException instead. Why? Observed using Hibernate 3.6.8 and [hibernate-jpa-2.0-api v1.0.1.Final](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.hibernate.javax.persistence%7Chibernate-jpa-2.0-api%7C1.0.1.Final%7Cjar)

> javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find bar.foo.Entity with id 144487
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration$Ejb3EntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(Ejb3Configuration.java:137)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.returnNarrowedProxy(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:320)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:277)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1090)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1005)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:998)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:779)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:754)

Comment: the stack trace provides enough info - it's all HB code, which you can see in hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.8-sources.jar in maven repo

Comment: No it doesn't. For example, it doesn't tell if the entity is already loaded in the session or not. It also doesn't say which entity class you're trying to find. But if you don't want to get help, don't provide any info.

Comment: Are you trying to `find()` `bar.foo.Entity` or some other entity that references it?

Comment: @jb nizet fair enough, I will constrict and post a test case. But look at the javadoc for EntityManager.find()  under no circumstances does it say EntityNotFound can be expected (unlike for get()) the impl should return the entity,null or throw IllegalStateException. It should never throw EntityNotFound. Or do you read the contract differently?

Comment: I think you're hitting a case that is not described in the contract. Like for example: the entity exists, but references an entity which doesn't.

Comment: I think @JBNizet has it right, as the contract for Hibernate Session.get() matches the contract for EntityManager.find(): return null if the entity doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem using Hibernate 4.1.x and wanted to provide a pointer to someone experiencing the same problem. In my case, as mentioned in previous comments, it wasn't the entity itself, but rather another entity referenced from the loaded entity. The strange thing was that this referenced entity did exist, but it was accessed in a different transaction/session and that made the difference. Since I was writing a test using spring the simple change of moving @transactional from the class level to a method broke the whole thing.